# Firebase Dynamiclinks is unable to parse universal link

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

I have an app on TestFlight that I'm trying to setup passwordless signin using emailid from FireBase.

**I've done the following:**

1. Enabled Passwordless sign in on Firebase console
2. Created a Dynamic link on Firebase.

```
httpsdotslashslash<custom domain>/login/?link=https://<custom domain>/login&isi=<app id from itunes connect. Looks like this: 167*******>&ibi=<bundleid>
```

3. Confirmed that `https://<custom domain>/apple-app-site-association` returns correctly. Note that I'm using Firebase hosting to host this site. And have confirmed that `https://<firebase-projectid>.firebase.app/apple-app-site-association` also returns the above. i.e. custom domain is correctly resolving to this firebase hosting url.
4. In Info, Added a url type with identifier 'appLink' and 'url scheme'
5. Ensured that my GoogleService-Info is current
6. Enabled Associated Domains in 'Signing and Capabilities' in my project Target under 'All' (not just Debug or Release)
7. Added `applinks:<customdomain>` and `activitycontinuation:<customdomain>`
8. In my 'SceneDelegate', I'm handling the dynamic link with

```
private func handleIncomingDynamicLink(_ incomingURL: URL) {
        DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingURL) { dynamicLink, error in
          guard error == nil else {
            return print("ⓧ Error in \(#function): \(error!.localizedDescription)")
          }

          guard let link = dynamicLink?.url?.absoluteString else { return }

          if Auth.auth().isSignIn(withEmailLink: link) {
            // Save the link as it will be used in the next step to complete login
            UserDefaults.standard.set(link, forKey: "Link")

          }
        }
      }
```

9. In my viewcontroller, have copied the code from Firebase's quickstart PasswordlessViewController.swift as is.

**Observed behavior:**

- The email link is being sent. Here's what it looks like though. Not sure if this is right.

```
httpsdotslashslash<custom domain>/?link=https://<firebase-projectid>.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?apiKey=<web api key>&mode=signIn&oobCode=25CRdL7n3qXNatDT2nEypR9UWy17E_G0ChlmqrkpznsAAAGGLYK3jQ&continueUrl=https://<custom domain>/login&lang=en&ibi=<bundleid>&ifl=https://<firebase-projectid>.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?apiKey=<web api key>&mode=signIn&oobCode=25CRdL7n3qXNatDT2nEypR9UWy17E_G0ChlmqrkpznsAAAGGLYK3jQ&continueUrl=https://<custom domain>/login&lang=en
```

- Clicking on this url in my email correctly opens my app. handleIncomingDynamicLink() is also called correctly. But it throws the error `ⓧ Error in handleIncomingDynamicLink(_:): The operation couldn’t be completed. Universal link URL could not be parsed by Dynamic Links.`

Have tried a bunch of things.
But, unable to proceed beyond this stage. Not sure what is wrong with my link. What is it supposed to look like when behaving correctly? Should i be doing something with the oobCode? Why are there two redirections?

Happy to assist with any other information. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve it by adding all my url prefixes to info.plist.

```
<key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
        <array>
          <string>https://<custom domain>/login</string>
          <string>https://<custom domain>/</string>
        </array>
```

More details at https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains#console